# Add LinearLayout to another LinearLayout programatically in fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-linearlayout

I absolutely don't understand how to add LinearLayout to another LinearLayout. Can U help me pls? I have XML file:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffdf33"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffdf33"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:onClick="detaily"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10sp" 
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nazev"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:text="@string/nazev"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adresa"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:text="@string/adresa"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

With 2 LinearLayouts inside each other. **I want to add some LinearLayouts with id "ll" to LInearLayout with id "hl" in Java code dynamically.** Everything is inside the fragment BTW.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);
              LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hl);
              LinearLayout myLayout1 = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ll);
              myLayout.addView(myLayout1);
        return rootView;
    }
```

I have logcat here:

```
03-20 11:21:23.580: E/AndroidRuntime(30529): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 11:21:23.580: E/AndroidRuntime(30529): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Comment: so what's your problem?

Comment: I want to add some LinearLayouts with id "ll" to LInearLayout with id "hl" in Java code dynamically.

Comment: Do you know, what I want? :-D

Comment: are you getting some logcat error?

Comment: Nobody knows the answer?